# C# Out of range even if there is a condition to prevent that

Tags: c#, range

I got an error that should not arise:

```
 Task[] lestasks = new Task[5];
 
 int idplayer =0;
 int numtask = 0;

 while (numtask < 5 && idplayer < players.Count)
      {
      lestasks[numtask] = Task.Run(() => { Updateplayer(players[idplayer])); });

      numtask++;
      idplayer++;
      }

 Task.WaitAll(lestasks);
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, idplayer is out of range.
But the while condition check if idplayer is not superior or egal to players.count.

So, how it's possible for players[idplayer] to be out of range if idplayer is inferior to players.count?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Also, when you catch the exception in your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), what is the actual value of `idplayer` and `numtask`?

Comment: The debugger will tell you. Did you tried debugging before asking?

Comment: What is `players`? What `Updateplayer` does?

Comment: Try debugging, when your code is actually run (you scheduled it with `Task.Run`), `idplayer` most likely has the value of `players.Count`.

Comment: Sounds like an "access to modified captured variable" problem. Try making a copy of `idplayer` in the body of the while loop (e.g. `int idplayercopy = idplayer;`) use that in the call inside `Task.Run()` instead., i.e. `Updateplayer(players[idplayercopy])`

Comment: So what could be happening is that `idplayer++` is incremented before the task for the last iteration has run, so `idplayer` will actually be out of range at that point. Then the task is actually started and it gets a the current value of `idplayer` which will be out of range. If you make a copy before starting the task and use that copy, then that situation cannot arise.

Comment: I tried with the debugger and the error arised when idplayer = 8, and in my running setup, players had a length = 8. That's why I didn't understand how it's possible to get this error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson is right, like the answer below and I confirm it after fix, it's because the task take longer to start than the loop to continue. idplayer is incremented before the task so idplayer got a too hight value.

Comment: Also in this case `foreach(var player in players.Take(5))` seems to be a nicer option (`foreach` compared to `for` creates a local copy automatically)

Comment: Or just `var lestasks = players.Take(5).Select(p => Task.Run(() => Updateplayer(p))).ToArray()`